# Need to return PHP responsetext to HTML div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Having trouble returning PHP response text to an HTML div. I'm successfully sending a variable to a PHP form via AJAX but can't for the life of me figure out how to inject it into the Success div without using Alert. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Form here:

```
<form name="codesubmit" id="codesubmit">
                        <div class="field">
                            <font color="black"><label for="codeentry">Unique Code:</label></font>
                            <input pattern=".{5,5}" class="form-control" type="text" id="codeentry" name="codeentry" maxlength="5" title="Enter 5-character unique code." required>
                        </div>
                      <div class="rsvp-button text-center"><button type="submit" class="hvr-sweep-to-right">Submit</button>
                      <div id="loding" style="display:none; padding-left:20px;"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loader"></div></div>
                      </form>
                      <div id="Success" class="successalert" style=" display:none;"> <strong>Thank you</strong>.
                            <p>ENTER RETURN VAR INFO HERE.</p></div>
                      <div id="Error" class="errorelert" style="display:none;"> <strong>Something went wrong, contact Ben Taylor please.</strong></div>
```

JS here:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $("#codesubmit").submit(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $("#loding").css("display", "inline-block");
        $.post("codesubmit.php", {
                UniqueCode: $("#codeentry").val()
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $("#loding").hide();
                    $("#Success").slideDown("slow");
                    //document.write("Test");

                    $("#codesubmit")[0].reset();
                }
                else {
                    $("#loding").hide();
                    $("#Error").slideDown("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#Error").slideUp("slow");
                    }, 30000);
                }
            });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

PHP here:

```
<?php

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $codeentry = trim($_POST["UniqueCode"]);

        // Testing: Send Back Code.

        echo $codeentry; ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$("#Success").html(data).slideDown("slow");`?

Comment: As mentioned by Michael, you need to append the data with JS to your HTML. The .html() function will do just fine.

Comment: Thanks guys - I am brand new to JS, but have experience with PHP.  This will wipe out whatever I initially put into Success, correct? If I want this to be stage one of an edit sequence, I presume I could just handle HTML returns within the PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .done(...) callback, you see the "data" parameter, that has what you echoed from PHP. I suggest to get the value in data and store it in the "p" tag you have in your form, something like this:

```
<div id="Success" class="successalert" style=" display:none;">
<strong>Thank you</strong>.
<p id="some_id">ENTER RETURN VAR INFO HERE.</p>
</div>
```

And then in the JS:

```
.done(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $("#loding").hide();
                    $("#Success").slideDown("slow");
                    // this should do the trick
                    $("#some_id").html(data);

                    $("#codesubmit")[0].reset();
                }
                ...
```